# PySimpleGUI creating Text with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tkinter, pysimplegui

I want to display some text using for loop and PySimpleGUI.
I have a code...

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

teams = ["a","b","c","d"]
layout =  [

        [sg.Text(teams[i]), sg.Radio('Pot A', "RADIO1", default=True),
        sg.Radio('Pot B', "RADIO1")],

]

window = sg.Window('hey').Layout(layout)
button, values = window.Read()
```

And because i would like to avoid hardcoding I want to use for loop to create more of text for me.
example of loop...

```
for i in range(len(teams)):
   #create some text
```

I dont know where to insert my loop to make it work or if it is possible at all.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure exactly how you're wanting to display your list of teams.

You've got a number of choices of how to do it regardless.  One of the easiest is list comprehensions.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

teams = ["a","b","c","d"]
layout =  [[sg.Text(team) , sg.Radio('Pot A', "RADIO1"+team, default=True),
        sg.Radio('Pot B', "RADIO1"+team)] for team in teams]

window = sg.Window('hey', layout)
button, values = window.read()
```

Creating layouts using loops is described in the PySimpleGUI documentation:
https://pysimplegui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#generated-layouts-for-sure-want-to-read-if-you-have-5-repeating-elementsrows

Answer (score 0):

For newscomer, you can also create a loop in such direction:

```
fire = ['F1', 'F2', 'F3', 'F4', 'F5', 'F6', 'F7', 'F8', 'F9', 'F10']
col = [[sg.Text('Fire', background_color='red', size=sz)]]
        # Create several similar fire buttons in the vertical column
        for card in fire:
            col += [
                [sg.Button(card, key=card)]
            ]
```

Comment: This is a nice pattern. I don't believe there's an example in the Cookbook that adds to a layout that's already started to be defined.  I like it!  There's also a way to do it with a list comprehension that I'll include.  THIS is what I like about Python & PySimpleGUI. It's the "fun" part for me.